# Use ingress with GCS bucket as a backend

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, google-kubernetes-engine, nginx-ingress

I'm trying to add Ingress to my GKE, that will be serving static from GCS. On the github i found this [issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/1809), but it does not work for me, unfortunately.
I have following config:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: google-storage-buckets
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: storage.googleapis.com

---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: website-static-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx-ingress
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /my-bucket-name
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/upstream-vhost: "storage.googleapis.com"
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /*
            backend:
              serviceName: google-storage-buckets
              servicePort: 443
```

But result(you can find screenshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bP6c7.png))is quite weird for me. I have an ingress service with no endpoint or ip address and as a serving pods i have a lot of my other services pods(it looks like all pods there are from services that have load balancer, but I'm not sure)

I cannot understand, what am i doing wrong and I would really appreciate the help.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: which version of nginx-ingress are you using ?

Comment: you don't have to use wildcard on the path just "/" and your bucket should be public.can you verify?

Comment: Thank you to all of you for your attention!
Just figured it out on this weekend. To use nginx-ingress it would be nice to install it first! Sorry=) Dummy me=)

Comment: Hello, not running for me but similar conf as you Yevhen. It would be nice if you can explain to us what  you install after. Normally I have a Ingress Nginx right because I use it too. Thanks. Nicolas